# Extracting characters from a powershell operation, to pipeline into another function

Tags: powershell, pipeline, text-extraction

```
#Where $ConfigPath = C:\App\Place\whatever.xml

$AirportCode = 
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($ConfigPath).Replace("%Airport_Code%","LHR")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($ConfigPath,$AirportCode)

$SystemID = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($ConfigPath).Replace("%System_ID%",$Env:COMPUTERNAME)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($ConfigPath,$SystemID)
```

So this snippet of powershell is reading an XML file, and then it replaces a %Airport_Code% Place-holder with the text for a static airport designator.. In this case London Heathrow or LHR. Since our naming conventions contain the first three characters of whatever the nearby airport is.. instead of having a static value for that replacement, I'd like to find a way for powershell to extract the first three characters from the system name, and swap this static value for the system name value instead..

The next bit, scans the same XML file, and replaces the %System_ID% with the current system name using the $Env:COMPUTERNAME variable...  The script currently works as presented above..

Question: How can I extract the first three characters from the output of the $Env:Computername and pipeline it into the first section such that the current value of LHR changes to the first 3 characters of whatever the system name is.. (Because we use 3 character designations of airports as part of our naming convention.)

Comment: I think I don't fully get what you try to achieve... but if your questions is how to get the first 3 letters of `$Env:Computername`, you can just do a simple `Substring`: `$Env:Computername.Substring(0,3)`.

Comment: I'll try and explain a bit more.. This is part of a new system deployment script. - The idea is that we image off of a golden image, and instead of previously having to go into each individual system and modify a number of %xxxx% flagged elements manually, the hope is that through this script we can streamline our deployments. We'll image the system, and name it.. the script can activate the application, and change the various features, and then change the location code because our software is essentially geo-locked (you can only log into it from specific locations.

Comment: can you show me what your getting now vs what you want to get?

Comment: What I get now, is a false flag set to TRUE, a location code hard set to LHR, and then a new system name using the correct host name like LHR-TS-E01.... But I have systems all over that are FRA-TN-V01, or BER-T1-E01 etc. - if I can pull those three characters, and re-use them in the Airport code replacement, then I can just have one script instead of like 70, each specific to a single zone.

Comment: Well is `$Env:Computername.Substring(0,3)` not working then?

Comment: Apologies - this is maybe my 3 script ever.. Would that look like: $AirportCode = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($ConfigPath).Replace("%Airport_Code%",$Env:Computername.Substring(0,3)
)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($ConfigPath,$AirportCode)

Comment: In theory, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just get the first 3 letters of the computer name and pipe to a function you can do :

```
Function SomeFunction{
        [cmdletbinding()]
        param(
            [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
            [string]$Id
        )
        $Id
}

($Env:COMPUTERNAME).Substring(0,3) | SomeFunction
```

Substring gets the 3 chars (Substring(Start index, How many chars)), The | is piping the 3 chars to a function SomeFunction. The [cmdletbinding] allows for the piping in the function, [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] tells which parameter will take the pipe data.

Answer (score 0):

Although is is not recommended to use string replacements on XML source code, I think in this case it is quite legit because you have prepared the xml nicely with the placeholders. Anyway, why not replace both placeholders in one go, like with:

```
$newConfig = (Get-Content -Path $ConfigPath -Raw) -replace '%Airport_Code%', ($Env:COMPUTERNAME.Substring(0,3).ToUpper()) `
                                                  -replace '%System_ID%', $Env:COMPUTERNAME
$newConfig | Set-Content $ConfigPath -Force
```

P.s. Note the 'backtick' after the first line of code. It means that the line continues. I just put it in for readability, but for PowerShell this is all one line of code:

```
$newConfig = (Get-Content -Path $ConfigPath -Raw) -replace '%Airport_Code%', ($Env:COMPUTERNAME.Substring(0,3).ToUpper()) -replace '%System_ID%', $Env:COMPUTERNAME
```